# Error 404 when using the <c:import> JSTL tag to import an HTML file in another folder in a JSP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, intellij-idea, jstl

I'm trying to include an HTML file I've made inside a JSP but I'm getting a strange error that I think has to do with the path of where the file is.  I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and developing for Google App Engine.

My problem is when I use the tag:

```
<c:import url="/HTML/sidebar.html"/>
```

The page looks like this

> **Error 404 /JSP/JSP/FrontPage.jsp**
>
> this is the content!!

When I don't use the import tag the page is generated and simply says

> this is the content!!

---

My web directory looks this:

- Web

  - CSS
  - HTML

    - sidebar.html
  - JSP

    - FrontPage.jsp
  - WEB-INF

Inside *FrontPage.jsp* I have the following:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
      <div class="sidebar">
          <c:import url="/HTML/sidebar.html"/>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
          this is the content!!
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The *sidebar.html* file is very basic:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Projects</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And finally I have the servet handling the front page which so far just has the *doGet* method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("On Front Page!");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP/FrontPage.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: I tried the files and the same web directory in eclipse and it worked so IntelliJ must work a little differently.  Could anyone explain how to make this work in IntelliJ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<c:import>` tag as

```
<c:import url="HTML/sidebar.html"/>
```

Since, the tag can import from outside the application context, the leading `/` is causing problems. The path specified is relative to the current URL request being processed; so, adjust it accordingly.

Comment: No luck I still get the page looking like 

**Error 404 /JSP/JSP/FrontPage.jsp**

this is the content!!